# When ListView Scrolls the top Bar Should Stay at top and ListView can only Scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make this type of view in my application. I know anyone of you have faced this problem.. [image] Please guide me how to make this type of view(Screen) in Android...

Comment: are you looking same as instagram section header?

Comment: Yes Kavi..Same as Instagram Section header..

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code i hope solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LinearLayout1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LinearLayout2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LinearLayout3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="9" >
</ListView>
```